# Stream lib returns null for tests

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

When strong swan runs the tests. It fails only with the following [tests](https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan/blob/master/src/libstrongswan/tests/suites/test_stream.c#L64) in the tests suite:

I am getting error

```
 Running suite 'stream':
Running case 'sync': -++
  Failure in 'test_sync': service != NULL (suites/test_stream.c:64, i = 0)
Running case 'async': -++
  Failure in 'test_async': service != NULL (suites/test_stream.c:129, i = 0)
Running case 'all': -++
  Failure in 'test_all': service != NULL (suites/test_stream.c:181, i = 0)
Running case 'concurrency': -++
  Failure in 'test_concurrency': service != NULL (suites/test_stream.c:222, i = 0)
```

Any ideas what could cause this problem? or how to debug it?